# PHP email attachment file

Tags: php, email-attachments, contact-form

i have created finally this code for a contact form and there is one thing missing as i want to but maximum size 5 MB and when if tried function `if($file_size > 5000000){$fileErr = "max allowed size is 5 mb";} else{$check6 = 1;}` but it didn't work  and the code is not working but if i remove this function  everything else will work great so any help with that and when i solve this problem i will add the code here so everyone can get a benefit from that .... and here is the code below

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Start PHP CODE -->
<?php
// Show errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 
// define Errors variables
$fnameErr = $lnameErr = $emailErr = $humanErr = $fileErr = $fileErr2 = $result =  "" ;
 
// when we press submit do the following
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// define contact form variables
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$design = $_POST['design'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$human = $_POST['human'];

// define Checks variables
$check1 = $check2 = $check3  = $check4 = $check5 = $check6 =  "";

 
// Let's do some checks 
// Checking the First Name
if(empty($_POST["fname"])){
 $fnameErr = "Name is Required";
}else{
 $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
 // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
      $fnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }else{
  $check1 = 1;
 }
}
// Checking the Last Name 
if(empty($_POST["lname"])){
 $lnameErr = "Name is Required";
}else{
 $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
 // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lname)) {
      $lnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }else{
  $check2 = 1;
 }
}
//Checking the Email Adress
if(empty($_POST["email"])){
 $emailErr = "Email is Required";
}else{
 $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }else{
  $check3 = 1;
 }
}
//Checking the Anti-Spam Question
if(empty($_POST["human"])){
 $humanErr = "Please Enter the Answer";
}else{
 if ($human != 4){
  $humanErr = "Please check your answer";
 }else{
  $check4 = 1;
 }
}
 
// checking the attachment
if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {
  
 $allowedExtensions = array("pdf","doc","docx");
 
 $files = array();
 foreach($_FILES as $name=>$file) {
  $file_name = $file['name']; 
  $temp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
  $file_type = $file['type'];
  $file_size = $file['size'];
  $path_parts = pathinfo($file_name);
  $ext = $path_parts['extension'];
  if(!in_array($ext,$allowedExtensions)) {
   $fileErr = "File $file_name has the extensions $ext which is not allowed";
  }else{
   $check5 = 1;
  }
  if($file_size > 5000000){
                $fileErr = "Max allowed size is 5 MB";
            } else {
                $check6 = 1;
            }
  
  array_push($files,$file);
 }

 
// define email variables
$to = 'eng.bolaraafat@gmail.com';
$from = "qyas.ae- contact form"; 
$subject = 'Contact Form';
$message = 'From: '.$fname .$lname."\r\n".
           'E-mail: '.$email."\r\n".
           'Telephone: '.$tel."\r\n".
           'Designation: '.$design."\r\n".
           'Country Appled From: '.$country."\r\n".
           'Message: '.$comment."\r\n"."\r\n";
$headers = "From: $from"; 
// boundary 
 $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
 $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 
  
 // headers for attachment 
 $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 
  
 // multipart boundary 
 $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
 $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
  
 // preparing attachments
 if(!empty($_FILES["my_file"])){
 for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
  $file = fopen($files[$x]['tmp_name'],"rb");
  $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]['tmp_name']));
  fclose($file);
  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
  $name = $files[$x]['name'];
  $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$name\"\n" . 
  "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$name\"\n" . 
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
  $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
 }}else{
  $fileErr = "Please Attach your Resume";
 } 
  
 
// Emailing the Contents if all Checks are correct 
if($check1 && $check2 && $check3 && $check4 && $check5 && $check6 == 1){
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 $result =  "Message Sent Sucessfully";
}else{
 $result = "Message Can't be sent";
}
} }
 function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
 
?>
<!-- END OF PHP CODE --> 


<h2>Contact Form</h2>
<p><span style="color: red" >*Required fields</span></p>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
 First Name:<input type="text" name="fname"><span style="color: red" >*  <?php echo $fnameErr ?> </span><br><br>
 Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname"><span style="color: red" >* <?php echo $lnameErr ?></span> <br><br>
 E-mail:<input type="text" name="email"><span style="color: red" >* <?php echo $emailErr ?></span> <br><br>
 Telephone:<input type="text" name="tel"><br><br>
 Designation:<select name="design">
    <option value="Architectural Engineer">Architectural Engineer</option>
    <option value="Structural Engineer">Structural Engineer</option>
    <option value="Draughts-man">Draughts-man</option>
    <option value="Receptionist">Receptionist</option>
    <option value="Secertary">Secertary</option>
   </select><br><br>
   Country Applied From:<select name="country">
  <option value="">Country...</option>
  <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
</select><br><br>
 Message:<textarea name="comment"></textarea> <br><br>
 Upload Your Resume:<input type="file" name="my_file"><span style="color: red; margin-left: -60px;" >*<?php echo $fileErr ?></span><br><br> 
 <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
 <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here"><span style="color: red" >*<?php echo $humanErr ?></span><br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 <input type="reset" value="Clear"><br><br>
<strong><?php echo $result ?></strong>
</form><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: You are using `$check5` for 2 different tests. The first sets it but your size check when it fails does not unset it

Comment: @RiggsFolly  first of all thanks for your reference second i have changed it to `$check6` its not submitting but no message showing with the error and i tired to put die but still no message showing and if the check is true (file size is less than 5 mb and its type is supported) the mail will be submitted diectly

Comment: Please update your code

Comment: If you put `die()` into the code, you will never get to the HTML which is where you output your error messages

Comment: @RiggsFolly  @Dipanwita Kundu i found that its doing that already without any condition and i think its found here in the functions `fopen` `fread` `fclose` as when iam uploading file more than 2MB even without condition it will reject it and give me error

Comment: Check `php.ini` and set `upload_max_filesize = 2M` to an approapriate value

Comment: @ RiggsFolly i modified it `upload_max_filesize = 5M`  and still nothing changed its giving error cant open the file if it is more than 2MB i lost hope in solving it

Comment: @ RiggsFolly i restarted the server and now its working good thank you so much for your help i appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set $check5=1 when `allowedExtensions` is true. Next to it, you check `file_size`. When your `file_size` > 5MB, `check5` was not reset or change. So if your attachment is proper & file_size > 5mb system will try to send email with attachment (which you don't want) as `check5==1`. So to stop it you need to set `check5=0` when file_size > 5MB.

Please update your code like :

```
if($file_size > 5000000){
       $fileErr .= "Max allowed size is 5 MB";
} else {
        $check6 = 1;
        array_push($files,$file);
 }
```

Hope this is clear

Comment: i changed second `$check5` to `$check6` and still the same result also the mail is not sent if size is bigger than 5 mb but the problem iam not recieving error message

Comment: Please put your `array_push()` inside `else` part   like: `    if($file_size > 5000000){
                $fileErr = "max allowed size is 5 mb";
            } else {
                $check5 = 1;   array_push($files,$file);
            }`

Comment: i updated it and still same error ... the problem is that its not submitting the email because file size is bigger than 5 mb but its not showing any message that file size is bigger than 5 mb may be because i defined same
`$fileErr` for `$check5` and `$check6`?

Comment: what is your  "post_max_size" & "upload_max_filesize"? If uploaded filesize > "upload_max_filesize", then `$file_size` = 0.So it will not enter that condition.Check your error log also for details.

Comment: @ Dipanwita Kundu i modified it `upload_max_filesize = 5M`  and still nothing changed its giving error cant open the file if it is more than 2MB i lost hope in solving it

Comment: That means your change was not saved..You need to update `post_max_size` also.`post_max_size` must be greater than  `upload_max_filesize`. Did you restart your server after updating the value?

Comment: you are so smart i just didn't restart the server now its working well.. thank you very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139850/discussion-between-dipanwita-kundu-and-paulrf).

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is correct and your code is also working fine. Please recheck.

Comment: its  working fine except only showing the message if the file size is larger than 5 mb but it will not submit the message unless file size less than 5 mb but no error message showing

Answer (score -1):

Try PHPMailer, I am using it there will be no problem.

```
<?php
/**
 * PHPMailer simple file upload and send example
 */
$msg = '';
if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {
    // First handle the upload
    // Don't trust provided filename - same goes for MIME types
    // See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004 for more thorough upload validation
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        // Upload handled successfully
        // Now create a message
        // This should be somewhere in your include_path
        require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
        $mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
        $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer file sender';
        $mail->Body = 'My message body';
        // Attach the uploaded file
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file');
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            $msg .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            $msg .= "Message sent!";
        }
    } else {
        $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PHPMailer Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if (empty($msg)) { ?>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000"> Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Send File">
    </form>
<?php } else {
    echo $msg;
} ?>
</body>
</html>
```